# Auto-launch Microsoft Teams by adding it to my "Login Items"

Tags: mojave, login-items

I want Microsoft Teams to start automatically every time I turn on/log into my (company) MacBook (running Mojave 10.14.5.

I can add it to my login-items under System Preferences -> Users & Groups, but the next time I start up it doesn't launch, and when I go back into System Preference, it's no longer listed in my login-items.

What should I try next?

Comment: Did you enable Autostart in the app itself first and then add in login items. 
In Microsoft Teams > Click on your avatar > Settings > General > tick Auto-start application

Comment: Yes, that worked!

Comment: I will put this as a solution. Would you be kind to accept the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, Enable Autostart in the app itself and then add in login items.

In **Microsoft Teams** > **Click on your avatar** > **Settings** > **General** > tick **Auto-start application**

This will allow you to Auto Launch the MS team from Login items.